# wso2esb how to validate addressing headers

Tags: mediator, ws-addressing, wso2-esb

I want to validate that the request url match exactly the addressing header To.

is it possible to do that in a class Mediator? 
how can I get the endpoint url of the proxy service?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you can do it with class mediator. But you can match the url with in the proxy service[1].

Also you can get the 'TO' value using message context property[2].

1.https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB451/Sample+157%3A+Conditional+Router+for+Routing+Messages+based+on+HTTP+URL,+HTTP+Headers+and+Query+Parameters
2.https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/Synapse+Message+Context+Properties#SynapseMessageContextProperties-Property:MESSAGE_FORMAT

Comment: the property 'To' returns the value of the ws addressing header, not the real service endpoint.

Comment: I couldn't find any synapse constant here[1] to get the the reals service endpoint. But message context has a method(getEndpoint) to get the endpoint .see the doc[2]. hope you can take use of that withing a class mediator.

1.https://synapse.apache.org/apidocs/constant-values.html#org.apache.synapse.SynapseConstants.ERROR_CODE
2.https://synapse.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/synapse/MessageContext.html#getEndpoint(java.lang.String)